# sudoers on Debian 9 installed from docker

Tags: debian, user-accounts

I've installed a tomcat docker image based on Debian9.
There is something weird with user creation I don't understand.

I'm root and I add an user with

```
useradd adminuser
```

No home directory is created...well. I create it.
I add a password to the user with

```
passwd adminuser
```

I add the user to sudoers with

```
usermod -aG sudo adminuser
```

(I have actually to install sudo with apt-get install sudo)

Now if I log as adminuser with

```
 su adminuser
```

Password is not asked. Second, I can't sudo (sudo command not found) nor I have common commands available to root like java...

I also see that there is no /etc/sudoers file...

What is wrong?

I add /etc/sudoers with

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

but nothing changes. Adding export PATH in ~/.bashrc I can get commands as root though, but not sudo.
I also add /bin/bash to /etc/passwd...as there was nothing

Answer (score 0):

You may want to install sudo:

```
apt install sudo
```

Then reconsider, as containers are not meant to be standalone systems, rather small bricks within a bigger picture.

Comment: I did install sudo indeed. The purpose of the container actually is to test some installations on centos without using virtual machines like VirtualBox